# Is there any json rest service out there that allows a javascript webapp to get the current UTC time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, utc

I'm looking for something like http://time.is/UTC but with an interface for web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an SLA-level service, there's a service here on Google App engine that speaks JSONP: http://json-time.appspot.com/

Requesting http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json will return an object like this:

```
{
  "tz": "UTC", 
  "hour": 23, 
  "datetime": "Wed, 30 Mar 2011 23:03:55 +0000", 
  "second": 55, 
  "error": false, 
  "minute": 3
}
```

If you append ?callback=yourJsonCallback, it will respond like:

```
yourJsonCallback({
  "tz": "UTC", 
  "hour": 23, 
  "datetime": "Wed, 30 Mar 2011 23:05:36 +0000", 
  "second": 36, 
  "error": false, 
  "minute": 5
})
```

James Padolsey has a nice blog post demonstrating how to consume the service with plain JavaScript and a variety of libraries like jQuery: http://james.padolsey.com/uncategorized/getting-the-real-time-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Does this fulfill your needs: http://developer.yahoo.com/util/timeservice/V1/getTime.html

Comment: Yes, but let me wait if there's a better answer. I would prefer to have the results immediately in UTC, rather than having to convert from PDT.

Answer (score 1):

Then there is this one : http://www.nanonull.com/TimeService/TimeService.asmx/getUTCTime
It returns UTC in the following format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.Nanonull.com/TimeService/">10:43 PM</string>
```

Which actually seems less helpful.